# Should I use 'error:' callback or just check the returned 'data' in ajax call?

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

Here is how I am submitting my ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "myurl",       
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : "text",
            data : ({
                json : myjson
            }),
            success : function(data) {

                if(data == 'success'){
                    //alert('success');
                }
                else {
                    alert('fail');
                }

                };
            }

        });
```

Within java im just returning the string which contains either 'success' or 'fail' depending on wether or not a exception is thrown :

pseudo code :

```
try {
return "success";
}
catch (Exception e){
return "fail";
}
```

Will this suffice instead of using the ajax error callback ? If not sufficient how should this callback be used and what extra failure conditions is it checking for ?

```
   error : function() {
                alert ('error');
    }
```

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, since I'm not big on jQuery, but I think the error callback is for things like network errors (in other words, situations in which your server-site Java can't or doesn't get back to you.

Comment: you are mixing up concept of server script error handling and ajax error...not the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `error` callback is different: jQuery will call that function if an error occurred during sending request or receiving a response.  For example, if your server doesn't return an answer but instead "500 Internal Server Error" (or any other error for that matter), then `success` callback function will not be called at all.  If you define the `error` callback, then it will be called - and you'll have some chance of figuring out what the error was.

Just because your server works perfectly doesn't mean that a communication error cannot occur: for example, it could be "Gateway timeout", "No route to host", etc.

Finally, if you declare `dataType: json` (I know it doesn't apply in your example) but the returned data cannot be parsed (i.e. it's not a well-formatted JSON string), your `error` function will be called and not your `success` function.

Comment: Good answer. I would add, it's always a good idea to provide an error callback, if for no other reason than to log the error so you can debug problems that occur in production, even if you don't notify the user.